# how to sort the documents in a collection in cloud firestore by their date of creation instead of their name?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

the datas saved into cloud firestore are sorted by name but i want it to be sort by the time im saving it into the cloud instead, how do i do that?

here's my code :

```
_fireStore.collection('orders')
    .document(_costumerPhoneNumber)
    .setData({
        'Phone Number': _costumerPhoneNumber,
        'Name': _costumerName,
        'NeighborHood/Complex': _costumerNeighboorHood,
        'Street/Building Number': _costumerStreetNumber,
        'House/Apartment Number': _costumerHouseNumber,
        'Shop Chosen': _selectedShop,
    });
```

Comment: Just use epoch time. instead of name

Comment: i dont understand can you please explain

Comment: you can't control the order of how data get saved. you can only order data when query.

Answer (score 0):

Query collectionReference = _fireStore.collection("orders").orderBy('field');